# How to catch a dplyr query in a string

Tags: r, dplyr

When using the `dplyr` package to manipulate tables in a database, it creates a sql statement that can be viewed by the `show_query` function. This sql statement is not executed except if you call `head`, `compute`, `collect` or `collapse`. In some cases, the sql statement generated by `dplyr` is more important than its execution (for example: to create functions for operations not yet implemented in some database packages, like `copy (subquery) into file_name;`)

I want to know: how do I get the sql created by `dplyr` and put it in a string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok. Looking into `dbplyr` source, I found that `dbplyr::sql_render` return the table sql statement, which can be used to compound another sql:

```
sql_query = dbplyr::sql_render(tbl_table)
```

Comment: You're right Fabio, the only thing I've seen about `sql_render()` is that it has not gone through the SQL optimizer, so it may return different results than `show_query()`

Comment: I've tested some very extensive and optimizer-prone queries and there is no difference between `dbplyr::sql_render()` and the `show_query()` soluction proposed by dvantwisk, except for the fact that the output of `dbplyr::sql_render()` is better formated.

Answer (score 6):

`show_query()` outputs the sql query generated by dplyr as a diagnostic messsage.  If the object `res` is the result of an sql query using dplyr, the sql query can be extracted and coerced to a character vector using `capture.output()`.  Each new line of the query is stored as an element in our `output` vector, so `paste(tail(output, -1),collapse="")` can be used to get the result as a length one character vector, as you wanted.  (I am removing the first element of the output vector for the final output since it is seems to just be the unnecessary tag "".)

```
## Capture 
output <- capture.output(res %>% show_query(), type="message")
## Concatenate character vector to a one length character vector
final_output <- paste(tail(output, -1), collapse="")
```